# angular2 Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?)

Tags: angular, angular2-services

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RestfulComponent } from '/app/rest/app.restful.component.ts';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    RestfulComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ RestfulComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.restful.module.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RestfulService } from '/app/rest/restful/restfull.service.ts';

import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="onTestGet()">GET TEST</button><br>
    <p>Output: {{getData}}</p>
  `,
  providers: [RestfulService] 
})
export class RestfulComponent {

    getData: string;
    postData: string;
//
   constructor (private _http: Http){}

      onTestGet(){
          this._restfulService.getCurrentTime().subscribe(
          data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
          error => alert(error),
          () => console.log("end")
              );
          }
}
```

**app.restful.component.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class RestfulService {
        constructor (private _http: Http){}

        getCurrentTime(){
            return this._http.get('http://date.jsontest.com').map(res => res.json());
        }
}
```

**restful.service.ts**

[image]

[[image]**test.html**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Cae.png)

I do not have much knowledge about angular. If in case you are missing any information or file, I am here to add.

I'll put the changed codes where they generated the following error:

What should I do??

Answer (score 2):

declare RestfulService inside the constructor method :

```
constructor(private _restfulService: RestfulService) { }
```